# Adding onCenter={} setting to react-native-image-pan-zoom triggers syntax error

Tags: android, react-native

This package works nicely in general. But when I add onCenter parameter, the Android app simulator will crash with a syntax error.

My image file is taller than the phone screen size. The default seems to be it displays the centre of the image.  And I’m trying to display the top part of the image. Users can swipe up and down to read through the rest of the image. 
I followed the  instruction on this page. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-pan-zoom

And I’ve tried both “centerOn” and “ICenterOn” with the same result.

```
<View>
<ImageZoom 
      cropWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
       cropHeight={Dimensions.get('window').height - 90}
       imageWidth={750}
       imageHeight={2175}
       pinchToZoom={true} 
      enableCenterFocus={false}
      centerOn={x: 100, y: 100, scale: 1, duration: 0.1}
               >
        <Image style={styles.map3}
               source={require('./assets/imageFile_01.png')}> . 
        </Image>
</ImageZoom>
</View>
```

The syntax error seems to suggest this method is not being recognised. 
Any pointer would be appreciated.

My environment:
Mac OS 10.14
React: 16.6.3
React Native: 0.58.4
react-native-image-pan-zoom: ^2.1.11
being tested on Android emulator

It looks like this tool is also called react-native-image-zoom.

https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-zoom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, fixed it by passing centerOn as an object (double braces):

```
centerOn={{x: 100, y: 100, scale: 1, duration: 0.1}}
```